# Prove the given identity using the shortest method possible

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Prove the given identity.
>   $$\left(\sin\frac{9\pi}{70}+\sin\frac{29\pi}{70}-\sin\frac{31\pi}{70}\right)\left(\sin\frac{\pi}{70}-\sin\frac{11\pi}{70}-\sin\frac{19\pi}{70}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{5}-4}{4}$$

Please provide the shortest method possible. I didn't get any idea to start the solution

Comment: i would multiply out these terms

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner,  I guess it would be more complex.

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner, is it possible to use Euler identity?

Comment: An answer is given in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1895204/help-with-this-trigonometry-problem

Comment: @divx Thank you for pointing out that I put the above info in the wrong place.